# Hiding a tab if it is left empty

Tags: tabs

I have created new custom tabs on my product pages (Datasheets, Ask A Question and Returns and delivery). At the moment in my Datasheet tab it displays the PDF or datasheet for that product but if there is no datasheet in the tab is displays a message. Is there any way iu can get the tab to hide if there isnt a datasheet in the tab instead of diaplying a message??

This is how the tab is created :

```
<reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild" ><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
                <action method="setTemplate" ><template>catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>pdf_tabbed</alias><title>Data Sheets</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/pdf.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
</reference>
```

This is my phtml file. This is what is displayed in the tab.

```
<?php $_pdf = $this->getProduct()->getPdf(); ?>
<?php if ($_pdf): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('PDF') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_pdf, 'pdf') ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    Sorry but there's no Data Sheet associated with this product!
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you if you can help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use javascript/jQuery to hide the tab in the `else` condition.

Comment: Just drop the else entirely.

Comment: if i just drop the else then the tab is still appearing it is just blank. And i will have to look into the javascript as i am rather new to java script.

Comment: @AdamAllen this happened to me before, it could be just a space or an enter, the tab shouldn't show if your response is really empty (no invisible characters either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using this IF statement

```
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>

    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>

    <?php else: 

     echo 'Sorry there no description for this product, if you require more information, please ask a question';?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a tab conditionally trough an observer:

Observe the event `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after`

Check for the catalog tabs block instance and add your tab when the datasheet has data.

```
           public function core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
               $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

               if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs) {
                    //add if data not empty condition
                        $block->addTab('tabname', array(
                               'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('tablabel'),
                               'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('tabtitle'),
                               'content' => $block->getLayout()->createBlock('myblock', 'myblockname')->toHtml()
                           ));
               }
           }
```

I appologize, this was for the backend, not the frontend as the op asked.